# How to use Z3 incrementally for abstraction refinement

Tags: z3, smt

I'm currently using the Z3 C++ interface to determine the abstraction of a system - the system can be thought of as a graph.

Now, to determine the outgoing transitions of a node I have to solve a forumla of the following form:

```
   guard   
&& b_0_0 == predicate_0 && b_0_1 == predicate_1 && ... && b_0_N == predicate_N
&& b_1_0 == predicate1_0 && b_1_1 == predicate1_1 && ... && b_1_N == predicateN_N
&& ...
&& b_M_0 == predicateM_0&& b_M_1 == predicateM_1 && ... && b_M_N == predicateM_N
```

where the `b_j_i` are the free variables and both the guard and the predicates are boolean formulas over integers, e.g. `guard` may be `x>y+1`. The `b_0_i` variables encode the source while the others (`b_j_i`,j>0) encode the possible destination nodes.

Solving this once works well and in acceptable speed. However this is where the problems start.

First of all, I need all solutions of this formula. Since Z3 doesn't have an AllSat-feature I'm currently determining all solutions by first pushing the solver state and adding the negation of the previous solution to the model until no satisfying valuations exist. In the end I pop the solver state to get rid of the 'negated solutions' which I only needed for enumeration.

At some later point of my analysis I may need to refine the abstract system. This boils down to solving the same formula extended by M assertions:

```
   guard   
&& b_0_0 == predicate0_0 && b_0_1 == predicate0_1 && ... && b_0_N == predicate0_N && b_0_N+1 == predicate0_N+1
&& b_1_0 == predicate1_0 && b_1_1 == predicate1_1 && ... && b_1_N == predicate1_N && b_1_N+1 == predicate1_N+1
&& ...
&& b_M_0 == predicateM_0 && b_M_1 == predicateM_1 && ... && b_M_N == predicateM_N && b_M_N+1 == predicateM_N+1
```

Clearly, it is desirable to exploit incrementality of Z3 in some way as most parts of the formula have been solved at some earlier point in time. However, the solver-object doesn't have any of the information derived at that earlier point due to the pushing and popping needed to enumerate all solutions of the first formula mentioned. Assumptions don't seem suitable, too (due to the necessity of enumeration).

Am I missing something? Is there an obvious way of exploiting the incrementality?

**edit**: I think it might be possible to enumerate all solutions using assumptions but I'm not sure about how an suitable encoding may look like. A primitive approach I thought of was to add an assertion 'last_solution == flag' (new flag for every new solution) and run the next check with the assumption !flag (which will basically disallow the respective solution). This approach, however, seems to generate tons of unnecessary (never used in later checks) assertions on the solver's stack, i.e. I must not set the flag's value in later checks (with more predicates) as this very flag may disable parts of solutions.